# Action Controller:Exception Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My site app runs when I push to heroku, but when i run localhost:3000, i get a "routing error" "no routes match "/".  I have been searching all over the place for a answer and cant find out what to do.  My routes.rb is listed below.  Thanks.

```
Kliqq::Application.routes.draw do



  get "home/index"
  get "welcome/index"

  resources :groups
  devise_for :admins
  devise_for :users


  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.

  root :to => "home#index"

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
  # match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end
```

I now realize the problem is with devise. when run it now i get "no devise_for" method.
here is my full trace.

```
config/routes.rb:2
```

actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:233:in `instance_exec'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:233:in`draw'
config/routes.rb:1
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in`load'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in`new_constants_in'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in`load'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:127:in `reload_routes!'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:127:in`each'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:127:in `reload_routes!'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:120:in`routes_reloader'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in`execute_if_updated'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:51:in `_callback_before_5'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:419:in`_run_prepare_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:45:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in`_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in`call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:46:in`call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in`call'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in`call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in`call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in`call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in`method_missing'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in`service'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in`run'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in`start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in`start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in`start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in`start'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/server.rb:213:in`start'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:30
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in`tap'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:27
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6

```
enter code here
```

Comment: What platform/framework is this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified Devise in your `Gemfile`? If you haven't, that would cause the "undefined method `devise_for`" error.